# Avoid accumulation of iterator types in template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

Following principle: when I want to return a collection from a function I will pass an output iterator and let the caller decide where the output should go.

Consider the class which has `n` methods and each one returns some collection. This mean that I need to construct class with `n` template parameters (output iterators). The number of template parameters will start to grow, and I don't know how to handle this problem.

Specific example:

```
template<class TNode, class TEdge> class AGraph;
template<class TNode, class TEdge, class OutputOfFunc1, class OutputOfFunc2>
class APathCalculation
{
    using TGraph = AGraph<TNode, TEdge>;
public:
    virtual void ReturnShortestPath(size_t source, size_t dest, TGraph& graph, OutputOfFunc1 outPath) = 0;//func1
    virtual void ReturnAllShortestDistances(size_t source, TGraph& graph, OutputOfFunc2 outDistances) = 0;//func2
};
```

And, I will derive different classes (e.g. Dijkstra, Bellman-Ford) from `APathCalculation`. But the problem is that I introduce template arguments

```
...class OutputOfFunc1, class OutputOfFunc2>
```

which I fell that they should not be in the class definition since they are specific to particular function.

Currently I declare the class like this

```
// Example of declaration
APathCalculation<
    int,    // type of node
    double, // type of edge
    back_insert_iterator<list<size_t>>,  // return type of shortest path between two nodes
    back_insert_iterator<vector<double>> // return type of shortest distances from source node
> &pathCalculator;
```

Comment: "I fell that they should not be in the class definition since they are specific to particular function" you know that you can make the individual methods templated?

Comment: @user463035818 I cannot make it template virtual. Implementation of path calculation is in derived class.

Comment: i am not sure if I understand your code, hence let me just ask another question. You know that Two classes, one derived from `APathCalculation<int,double,some_iterator_type_A>` and another deriving from `APathCalculation<int,double,some_iterator_type_B>`, are completely unrelated (ie they do not share a common base class) ?

Comment: @user463035818 Let's say that I want to make different implementaion of shortest path (in derived classes). If base class function return e.g. `vector<TEdge>` then I do not have this problem. But I want more general solution, I do not want to put `vector` in abstract class declaration (why function wouldn't be able to return list for example).

Comment: i think it would help if you made your example a bit more complete. eg. what is the class which has n methods and each one returns some collection? In the best case you could provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the code you would like to write together with the error messages you get

Comment: @Dejan His question was not about that. The question is "why do you implement the algorithms in derived classes of that base class? Why use polymorphy?". If the answer to that is "because I want to store different instances of that algorithm through the base class interface", then his point is "you can't do that if the base classes are different template instantiations".

Comment: In other words: Why use virtual functions here?

Comment: @MaxLanghof yes more or less what I wanted to say :)

Comment: @MaxLanghof I think that it make sense to derive all path calculation algorithms from the same base class. Client (caller of path calculation) is not interested in how the path is calculated. He is interested only how the results will be presented to him. Am I wrong?

Comment: The point is that `BaseClass<Iterator1>` and `BaseClass<Iterator2>` are not the "same base class". Is there anything in your code that would not work if there was no base class and no virtual functions, just the implementations? If so, please add it to the question. If not, the answer is "template the functions on the iterator, not the class" (and don't make them virtual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three alternatives to consider:

**Option 1: Just pick a type and return it**

If you're worried about performance, this likely isn't nearly as bad as you think.

```
virtual std::vector<TEdge> FindShortestPath(size_t source, size_t dest, TGraph& graph) = 0;
```

**Option 2: Accept a callback**

The idea is that the caller will supply a lambda that stores the output in whatever way makes sense.

```
virtual void TraverseShortestPath(
 size_t source,
 size_t dest,
 TGraph& graph,
 std::function<void(TEdge*)> callback) = 0;
```

**Option 3: Use a function template**

It's a little mysterious to me why you want to use polymorphism for this.  You could write function templates for different shortest path algorithms (similar to the algorithms style in the STL):

```
template <class TGraph, class OutIt>
void FindShortestPath(size_t source, size_t dest, TGraph& graph, OutIt output)
{
  // details...
}
```

There are of course lots of variations you could do on these approaches.  I would also caution against the use of output iterators like this.  The caller could pass something safe like a `back_inserter` but could also pass in something dangerous like a raw pointer, which could easily lead to a buffer overrun.

Comment: In option 3: I am loosing polymorphism. Option 1 is not general since I am specifying the return type. But option 2  sounds interesting, something that it doesn't came to my mind. Maybe, I should think to write library in that way.

Comment: Option (3) looses _runtime_ polymorphism, but why do you need it?  Do you really expect users of your library to choose different shortest path algorithms at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

> "Consider the class which has n methods and each one returns some
>   collection. This mean that I need to construct class with n template
>   parameters (output iterators).

No, you don't. You coudd in fact create a class with 0 template parameters. However, each method itself has one template parameter. In your case, you can reduce it to just 2 template parameters for the class:

```
template<class TNode, class TEdge>
class APathCalculation
{
    using TGraph = AGraph<TNode, TEdge>;
public:
    template<class OutputOfFunc1>
    void ReturnShortestPath(size_t source, size_t dest, TGraph& graph, OutputOfFunc1 outPath);

    template<class OutputOfFunc2>
    void ReturnAllShortestDistances(size_t source, TGraph& graph, OutputOfFunc2 outDistances);
};
```

Please note that I have made one important change here: this is a class in the OO sense. What you had was an *abstract* class or *interface*. Abstract classes are a good way to decouple caller and callee, but here you **cannot** decouple them: the caller and callee must agree on iterator types.

Comment: You lost virtual, polymorphism and decoupling. If the caller calls only one function, he must agree on output iterator types. That is fine. But that caller function also need to agree on other `n-1` iterators which he doesn't use. This part is bad.

Comment: @Dejan: No, they don't. Not in this solution. The caller of `APathCalculation<TNode, TEdge>::ReturnShortestPath<OutputOfFunc1>` clearly does not need to specify `OutputOfFunc2`. I indeed removed polymorpism, intentionally.

Comment: Yes in that case. But you lost polymorphism then. Having abstract class for path calculation makes sense to me. Will you design your library without such abstract class?

Comment: @Dejan: Yes. That is the modern C++ style. All those iterators do not share an abstract base class either.

Comment: @Dejan its not clear how you intend to use the base class. Note that already "And, I will derive different classes (e.g. Dijkstra, Bellman-Ford) from APathCalculation." is strictly speaking wrong. In your code `APathCalculation` is not a class, its just a template, as such you cannot derive from it. You **first** have to instantiate it. Classes deriving from two different instantations of the same template are not polymorphic

Comment: @user463035818 I will derived it like this: `template<class TNode, class TEdge, class OutputOfFunc1, class OutputOfFunc2>
 class Dijkstra : public APathCalculation<TNode, TEdge, OutputOfFunc1, OutputOfFunc2>`, the usual way how you derive classes.

Comment: @Dejan i dont see why there must be polymorphism. A `Dijkstra< A,B,C,F>` will not share a common base with a `Dijkstra<A,B,D,F>`. Sorry, for being stubborn, I usually avoid inheritance as much as I can, so "the usual way how you derive classes" does not really clarify my doubts

Comment: @Dejan: Except that these are templates, not classes.

Comment: @user463035818 I am really trying to understand why you said that I do not need polymorphism, but without success. I intended to use this code like this `template<class TNode, class TEdge, class OutputOfFunc1, class OutputOfFunc2>
 void client(APathCalculation& cal) { cal.ReturnShortestPath(...); }`. And this is polymorphism. I will propagate template parm across project to the very end.

Comment: @Dejan with your approach you can treat a Dijkstra or Bellman-Ford polymorpically only if they are working with the same types of iterators, but you cannot treat a Dijkstra working with iterator type A and a Dijkstra working with iterator type B polymorphically. This is what I find fishy, but maybe thats just what you want....

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, exactly. I want threat them in the same way (with polymorphisam) when they are created with same iterators. And this will be always true, because each caller function (like the `client` I previously wrote) will also accept iterators.

Answer (score 0):

You may define all your arguments in a single structure and use them all over your structures like this:

```
template<class TNode, class TEdge> class AGraph;

template< typename TYPE_DEFS >
class APathCalculation
{
    using TGraph = AGraph<typename TYPE_DEFS::TNode, typename TYPE_DEFS::TEdge>;
public:
    virtual void ReturnShortestPath(size_t source, size_t dest, TGraph& graph, typename TYPE_DEFS::OutputOfFunc1 outPath) = 0;//func1
    virtual void ReturnAllShortestDistances(size_t source, TGraph& graph, typename TYPE_DEFS::OutputOfFunc2 outDistances) = 0;//func2
};


template< typename TYPE_DEFS > 
class Dijkstra: public APathCalculation<TYPE_DEFS>
{
    using TGraph = AGraph<typename TYPE_DEFS::TNode, typename TYPE_DEFS::TEdge>;
public:
    virtual void ReturnShortestPath(size_t source, size_t dest, TGraph& graph, typename TYPE_DEFS::OutputOfFunc1 outPath) override {}
    virtual void ReturnAllShortestDistances(size_t source, TGraph& graph, typename TYPE_DEFS::OutputOfFunc2 outDistances) override {}
};

struct TypeDefs
{
    using TNode = int;
    using TEdge = double;

    using OutputOfFunc1 = std::back_insert_iterator<std::list<size_t>>;
    using OutputOfFunc2 = std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<double>>;
};

int main()
{
    Dijkstra<TypeDefs> d;
}
```

All that will not change anything of your binary. It only makes it a bit more convenient. But maybe I have misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0):

A "shallow" answer:

In order to avoid N template parameters in one class, you need to split it into N classes with 1 template parameter each.

A "deep" answer:

You cannot easily combine *dynamic* (runtime) polymorphism of virtual functions with *static* (compile-time, template based) polymorphism of its argument types. If users of the `APathCalculation` interface want to provide their own iterator class, they will need to instantiate all the potentially useful actual implementations of this interface for their iterator class, which makes dynamic polymorphism for `APathCalculation` a redundant idea.

If you really need dynamic polymorphism, you need a dynamically polymorphous iterator class.

You can actually have both (statically polymorphous template specializations for common algorithms and/or common iterators, backed by a "default" case that is a wrapper to dynamically polymorphous implementations), but that's probably too complicated for your task. Besides, you will still need a way to bind your "default" wrapper to the actual algorithm you want the `APathCalculation` client to call.

I personally would start with a purely template-based solution, but I could understand someone starting with a purely virtual function based solution.

Comment: `If you really need dynamic polymorphism, you need a dynamically polymorphous iterator class.` I don't understand this. Can you explain what you mean with this? How the signature in abstract class will look like in that case?

Comment: It could be a functor (either `std::function` or a class with a virtual function interface), or, if you want to use in place of "normal" output iterators, it could be a wrapper class that satisfies [`OutputIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator) requirements and redirects the required operator calls to the underlying polymorphous class (which it may hold by reference). You can look at the [`std::back_insert_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_insert_iterator/) implementation in order to see which methods you need to implement.